# Virtual Python installation not allowing ez_setup?

Tags: software-installation, python, non-root-user

I don't have root on my system, so I'm trying to create a virtual Python installation. I ran `virtual-python.py`, and it told me to run `ez_setup.py`. I found it online and ran it with the command `virtual-python.py` gave me, and it told me I don't have permission to edit some folder in /Library (which I don't). What would be something I can do instead of this? Also, how could I install py2app in this virtual installation?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this, from another stack overflow thread...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348869/how-to-install-virtualenv-without-using-sudo

I used this procedure some time back, on a system where I didn't have root permissions.